# Поддержка Java в VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, java

Здравствуйте! В общем пытаюсь настроить VS Code для компиляции java-файлов.
Установил расширения:

1. **Language Support for Java(TM) by Red Hat**
2. **Java Debug**

В настройках VS Code прописал путь к JDK:

`"java.home": "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_131"`

Пишу обычный Hello world -> Alt+C -> Выдает ошибку:

*'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.*

Кто сталкивался с подобным? Толковой пошаговой инструкции настройки VS Code под Java так и не нашел.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VSCode пытается запустить javac, но не знает, в какой директории он лежит. Для обнаружения бинарников в таких ситуациях в операционных системах есть переменная окружения PATH - она содержит все директории, в которых могут оказаться искомые бинарники. Таким образом вам нужно отредактировать переменные окружения, добавив в PATH `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131` (или поддиректорию, в которой находится javac.exe). Конкретные действия для редактирования переменных окружения могут разниться в зависимости от версии Windows, поэтому мне ничего не остается кроме как скопировать содержимое https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml

> #### Windows 10 and Windows 8
>
> - In Search, search for and then select: System (Control Panel)
> - Click the Advanced system settings link.
> - Click Environment Variables. In the section System Variables, find the PATH environment variable and select it. Click Edit. If the PATH environment variable does not exist, click New.
> - In the Edit System Variable (or New System Variable) window, specify the value of the PATH environment variable. Click OK. Close all remaining windows by clicking OK.
> - Reopen Command prompt window, and run your java code.
>
> #### Windows 7
>
> - From the desktop, right click the Computer icon.
> - Choose Properties from the context menu.
> - Click the Advanced system settings link.
> - Click Environment Variables. In the section System Variables, find the PATH environment variable and select it. Click Edit. If the PATH environment variable does not exist, click New.
> - In the Edit System Variable (or New System Variable) window, specify the value of the PATH environment variable. Click OK. Close all remaining windows by clicking OK.
> - Reopen Command prompt window, and run your java code.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Помогло добавление в PATH C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin